# Frequency of a value in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am scanning licence plates at my car wash company. Every plate is written to a database with plate, and datetime.

I would like to know now, if a customer is here for the first time, or if he has been here in the last 12 months already.

Using this query I get first results:

```
WITH thisMonth AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT pl.plate
  FROM POS.dbo.plate AS pl
  WHERE pl.datetime >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 1)
),
past12Months AS (
   SELECT  pl.plate
   FROM POS.dbo.plate AS pl
   WHERE pl.datetime >= 
     CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1, MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 1)) AS DATE)
)
SELECT count(tm.plate) as frequency, tm.plate as plate
FROM thisMonth as tm
right join past12Months as pm ON tm.plate = pm.plate
group by tm.plate
```

| frequency | plate |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | TUT_D_7-DEU |
| 1 | TUT_BM_224-DEU |
| 3 | TUT_AI_789-DEU |
| 1 | TUT_RS_261-DEU |
| 3 | TUT_EG_123-DEU |
| 7 | TUT_V_741-DEU |

My goal is to get to know how many plates have a frequency = 1 and how many do have a frequency > 1. In best case I get this as percentage.

Sample Data could be like this. The last 4 rows are plates which were there before. So they are existing customers. the other plates are there only once. so they are new customers.

| plate_id | plate | datetime | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15736 | TUT_UK_70-DEU | 2023-02-09 14:09:59.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.400 |
| 15737 | TUT_MW_941-DEU | 2023-02-09 14:11:09.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.403 |
| 15738 | TUT_RP_88-DEU | 2023-02-09 14:13:11.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.417 |
| 15739 | TUT_KB_666-DEU | 2023-02-09 14:14:06.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.417 |
| 15740 | TUT_IP_22-DEU | 2023-02-09 14:16:23.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.417 |
| 15741 | SIG_FR_608-DEU | 2023-02-09 14:17:19.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.420 |
| 15742 | TUT_EA_39-DEU | 2023-02-09 14:21:00.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.420 |
| 15743 | TUT_F_1976-DEU | 2023-02-09 14:23:05.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.420 |
| 15744 | TUT_UH_11-DEU | 2023-02-09 14:25:52.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.420 |
| 15745 | TUT_KF_509-DEU | 2023-02-09 14:26:41.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.420 |
| 15746 | TUT_BZ_999-DEU | 2023-02-09 14:27:30.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.420 |
| 15747 | TUT_M_995-DEU | 2023-02-09 14:29:54.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.420 |
| 15748 | TUT_JR_247-DEU | 2023-02-09 14:33:38.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.423 |
| 15749 | TUT_KF_509-DEU | 2023-02-09 15:26:41.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.420 |
| 15750 | TUT_BZ_999-DEU | 2023-02-09 15:27:30.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.420 |
| 15751 | TUT_M_995-DEU | 2023-02-09 15:29:54.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.420 |
| 15752 | TUT_JR_247-DEU | 2023-02-09 15:33:38.0000000 | 2023-02-21 12:50:19.423 |

Total plates are 17. Plates with frequency = 1 are 13. plates with frequency > 1 are 4.

Result should be like:
New Customers: 76%
Returning Customers: 24%

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you. I'm not convinced thatthat query is doing what you *think* it is.

Comment: How do you get 80% and 20% for 3 plates? You'd need at least 5 plates to get those numbers (4 existing, 1 new).

Comment: Right now there are about 30.000 plates registered

Comment: But you've only given us details of 3 plates, not 30. It's impossible to get the numbers you want from the sample data you've given us. The expected results should be representative of the sample data.

Comment: I hope the change helps....

Comment: Your sample data has that the date time for everyone is 2023-02-09 and they were all last updated on 2023-02-21. How do you know which of those visited in the last month? Or is the query you have, where you compare those from the last month to the last 12 a false flag here?

Comment: I am having trouble showing you a sample that satisfies you. Every day i get around 100 plates registered. I don't know how to make up a sample that shows you all the conditions (From this Month, compared to last 12 months, only once there or there more than once)

Comment: *"Total plates are 17. Plates with frequency = 1 are 13. plates with frequency > 1 are 4."* This doesn't add up. Your sample data only has 17 rows, not 17 plates; if you have 13 plates that only show up once and the rest 2 (or more) then there would need to be at least 21 rows. HOw are you getting those numbers from the sample data you provided?

Comment: Sorry Thom, I feel like a student getting punished by the teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH
  last_year
AS
(
  SELECT
    plate,
    COUNT(*)        AS freq
  FROM
    POS.dbo.plate
  WHERE
    datetime >= CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1, MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 1)) AS DATE)
  GROUP BY
    plate
  HAVING
    MAX(datetime) >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 1)
)
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN freq > 1 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END)
  /
  COUNT(*)
    AS percent_returnees
FROM
  last_year
```

Only look at plates that have been here in the last year.

Count their frequency of visits in that year.

Keep only those that visited in the last month.

Divide "visited more than once in the year" by "all"

Comment: This one is not working. Having trouble in the CAST line

Comment: @GeorgHuber I just copied that from your code, but missed `AS DATE)` by mistake.

Comment: Returns 83.4% for my table. That sounds very plausible....but I am working on understanding the query

Comment: You are using two dates. One in the WHERE and one in the HAVING....
WHERE returns 2022-08-01
Having returns 2023-09-01

Comment: There WHERER limits the last year and HAVING limits the current month right?

Comment: @GeorgHuber Yes (the date calculations are copied from your code)

Answer (score 0):

The maths in your expected results appears to be wrong, or your sample data is wrong; I don't know which. You state that you have 17 plates in your sample data, 13 that appear once, and 4 that appear more than once, but there are *only 17 rows* in your sample data. If you you 13 rows that have a distinct value once that only leaves 4 rows, which means that if they are duplicates there are only be *2* different plates, not 4.

Looking at your sample data, 4 plates do appear twice, however, only 9 appear once; I don't know where you got the other 4 from. If we use those numbers, you get ~69% and ~31%, not  76% and 24%.

```sql
WITH Visits AS(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS VisitNumber
    FROM(VALUES(15736,'TUT_UK_70-DEU','2023-02-09T14:09:59.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.400'),
               (15737,'TUT_MW_941-DEU','2023-02-09T14:11:09.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.403'),
               (15738,'TUT_RP_88-DEU','2023-02-09T14:13:11.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.417'),
               (15739,'TUT_KB_666-DEU','2023-02-09T14:14:06.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.417'),
               (15740,'TUT_IP_22-DEU','2023-02-09T14:16:23.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.417'),
               (15741,'SIG_FR_608-DEU','2023-02-09T14:17:19.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.420'),
               (15742,'TUT_EA_39-DEU','2023-02-09T14:21:00.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.420'),
               (15743,'TUT_F_1976-DEU','2023-02-09T14:23:05.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.420'),
               (15744,'TUT_UH_11-DEU','2023-02-09T14:25:52.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.420'),
               (15745,'TUT_KF_509-DEU','2023-02-09T14:26:41.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.420'),
               (15746,'TUT_BZ_999-DEU','2023-02-09T14:27:30.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.420'),
               (15747,'TUT_M_995-DEU','2023-02-09T14:29:54.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.420'),
               (15748,'TUT_JR_247-DEU','2023-02-09T14:33:38.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.423'),
               (15749,'TUT_KF_509-DEU','2023-02-09T15:26:41.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.420'),
               (15750,'TUT_BZ_999-DEU','2023-02-09T15:27:30.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.420'),
               (15751,'TUT_M_995-DEU','2023-02-09T15:29:54.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.420'),
               (15752,'TUT_JR_247-DEU','2023-02-09T15:33:38.0000000','2023-02-21T12:50:19.423'))V(plate_id,plate,datetime,updated_at)
    WHERE V.datetime >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, SYSDATETIME())
    GROUP BY Plate)
SELECT AVG(CASE VisitNumber WHEN 1 THEN 1. ELSE 0. END) AS NewCustomers,
       AVG(CASE VisitNumber WHEN 1 THEN 0. ELSE 1. END) AS ExistingCustomers
FROM Visits;
```

Comment: I think it's meant to be a proportion of the visitors in the last month. (last year defines whether they're a returnee, but last month defines whether they're included)

Comment: I chanced it to my database. And I get results as follows: NewCustomers 0.486630, ExistingCustomers 0.513369
I am just surprised for the "AVG". Why using Average if I want to count things? Count which plate has been there once or which plate has been there more than once

Comment: Average function is there to mitigate the grouping by Plate. Otherwise SQL throws an error. That is technical side. Plus logically it converts counts into percentages as requested.

Comment: Because using an `AVG` is the easiest way. Otherwise you'd need to the `COUNT` of new/existing divided by the total `COUNT`; which (surprise) gives you an average.

Comment: *"Otherwise SQL throws an error.*" The above doesn't throw an error. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5q6SHDgx)

Comment: Ok, looking at the CTE you pic all plates from the past 12 months and you look how often they where at my site. What I want to do is a little different. I want to look at the plates registered during this month (e.g. september) and look if they where here during the period from 2022-09-14 till 2023-09-14

Comment: How do you know they were registered this month? All the dates are for February. Nothing was registered *this* month according to that data.

Comment: This Data was selected with SELECT TOP(100)....data is available allmost day by day.

Comment: I'm talking about the sample data you provided, @GeorgHuber . That's the data we will use to answer your question, we can't access your database, not should be be able to. None of your sample data has data for this month, so talking about data from *this month* makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the column [datetime] is the date that the customer came for a car wash so what you could do something like this

```
SELECT final.result,customers_count * 100.0 /SUM(customers_count)
FROM
(SELECT 'Existing' AS result, existing.customers_count 
FROM
    (SELECT SUM(COUNT(plate)) OVER() AS customers_count
    FROM POS.dbo.plate 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH,GETDATE(),[datetime])<=12
    GROUP BY plate 
    HAVING COUNT(plate) >1) existing
UNION 
SELECT 'Newcomers' AS result, newcomers.customers_count
FROM
    (SELECT SUM(COUNT(plate)) OVER() AS customers_count
    FROM POS.dbo.plate 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH,GETDATE(),[datetime])<=12
    GROUP BY plate 
    HAVING COUNT(plate)=1) newcomers)final
```

What I did is find the number of people that came for more than one time and the number of people that came exactly once and in the end I calculated the percentages.

Comment: thats right....datetime is the time the camera registered the plate.